# Dynamic return path using Freeform hook

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have built an extension using the **freeform_module_insert_end** hook according to Solspace Extensions documentation as I want the form to redirect to a custom url including a unique hash - but for some reason I cannot get the hook to fire. I have pasted the code below:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Freeform Redirect Extension class
 *
 * @package        freeform_redirect
 */
class Freeform_redirect_ext {

    var $name            = 'Freeform Redirect';
    var $version         = '1.0.0';
    var $description     = 'Redirect to custom url';
    var $settings_exist  = 'n';
    var $docs_url        = '';

    var $settings        = array();

    /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param   mixed   Settings array or empty string if none exist.
         */
        function __construct($settings = '')
        {
            $this->settings = $settings;
        }

    /**
     * Activate Extension
     *
     * This function enters the extension into the exp_extensions table
     *
     * @see https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html for
     * more information on the db class.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function activate_extension()
    {
        $this->settings = array(
            'max_link_length'   => 18,
            'truncate_cp_links' => 'no',
            'use_in_forum'      => 'no'
        );


        $data = array(
            'class'     => __CLASS__,
            'hook'          => 'freeform_module_insert_end',
            'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
            'priority'  => 10,
            'version'   => $this->version,
            'enabled'   => 'y'
        );

        ee()->db->insert('extensions', $data);
    }


    /**
     * Disable Extension
     *
     * This method removes information from the exp_extensions table
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function disable_extension()
    {
        ee()->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
        ee()->db->delete('extensions');
    }

public function freeform_module_insert_end($inputs, $entry_id, $form_id, $obj)
{
    if ( ! $obj->edit AND
         ( ! $obj->multipage OR
            ($obj->multipage AND $obj->last_page)
         )
    )
    {
        $obj->params['return'] = 'thank-you/'.ee()->input->post('unique_hash');
    }
}

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

} // End Class Freeform_redirect_ext

/* End of file ext.freeform_redirect.php */
```

Comment: Try putting in something like 
echo "the hook fired";
exit();
at the top of your method. If that works, the extension is firing. It may be the conditional that is the issue

Comment: you are also missing a method call to match the hook
'method'    => 'freeform_module_insert_end', in your $data array.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I have added the 'method' => 'freeform_module_insert_end'  to the $data array and also placed the 'hook fired' inside the public function above 'if ( ! $obj->edit AND' but there is no notice saying the hook fired. What else could I be missing here?

Comment: Did you make sure your extension installed properly? i. e did you look in the extensions table and see if there was an entry for it and the data is correct? I'm assuming you installed the extension. I know I'm asking the obvious questions. But that's where I would start.

Comment: Hey Jim, uninstalled and reinstalled the extension and it works now! Thanks again for helping me with this. Cheers

Comment: When you added the method to the array, it doesn't automagically add it to the extensions table, you need to either reinstall or update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also missing a method call to match the hook 'method' => 'freeform_module_insert_end', in your $data array. Uninstall and reinstall the extension.